# real time drawing into many charts

Tags: c#, winforms, mschart, real-time-updates

I tried plot real time signal into MS Chart Winforms, when I'm plotting data into 1 or 3 charts everything is OK. Problem start when I plotting data into 5 chart with sampling frequency 500 Hz, interesting is when I plot with sampling frequency 250 or 1000 Hz, everything work fine. 
Sorry for my English, I am just learning. 
Thank you for your help.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Charts are for human eyes.  They can't see you adding 250 points per second so a real-time demand is pointless.  When you ignore that then you'll likely run into the next limitation, your UI thread burning 100% core trying to keep up.  You'll have to re-think this.

Comment: I use 1 separate thead for updating data in chart from serial port and  I update chart after every 50 samples and series is set as FastLine.  How I wrote, I have problem only with 500 samples, when I used 250 or 1000 samples per second everything work fine without time delay. Do you have any idea why 1000 samples working fine and 500 not ?

Comment: Sounds funny but no, without more info and no code we can't say..